# How to properly add Expo to an existing react-native app within an NX monorepo?

Tags: typescript, react-native, dependency-management, monorepo

I have a NX monorepo with a react native app. I need to install expo (cause I need to use some libs like ExpoAV) to the app, should I run yarn add expo at the workspace level or at the react-native app level?

What would be the right process to install, in general, dependencies that have their "stuff" to setup during an install?

**Update**

When I try to install the expo module from the workspace directory I get "'Expo/Expo.h' file not found at #import <Expo/Expo.h>" just doing the followings:

- create a nx workspace
- yarn add expo (in the workspace directory)
- manual setup of expo
  (changing AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.mm)
- pod install in the ios folder of the app
- npx nx run-ios [appname]

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `react-native` app you have already setup with `NX` is a "bare" react-native app. So it's not using expo. Expo is a kind of convenience walled garden to develop react-native apps. One can "eject" from an expo react-native project to a "bare" react-native project. This is often necessary once you need libraries which are not yet compatible with an expo react-native app.

So you've got a "bare" react-native app on your hands in your monorepo. Which is totally fine. You can still use all of the expo modules in your app as well. The setup to use them is a bit more cumbersome than other a basic react-native library.

They have a proper guide how to integrate Expo in your "Bare Workflow React-Native" app here:

Introduction: https://docs.expo.dev/bare/hello-world/

Guide to add Expo to Bare Workflow:
https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/

Comment: Sure, but my question is regarding the nx monorepo workflow. Should I install the react native modules in the workspace or in the app folder? If I install it in the workspace folder how the autolinking would work?

Comment: Unreleated to expo, `react-native` modules should be installed in the nx workspace directly, so not in the `app/` folder. I expect this to also work fine with `expo` and expo modules. 
`Nx` is smart about the modules and will link them to your apps and libraries in your workspace accordingly. Works flawlessly for me.

Comment: Actually I get "'Expo/Expo.h' file not found at #import <Expo/Expo.h>" just doing the followings:
- create a nx workspace
- yarn add expo (in the workspace directory)
- manual setup of expo (changing AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.mm)
- pod install in the ios folder of the app
- npx nx run-ios [appname]

Comment: Maybe `Nx` is not picking up that you want to use `Expo` in your app as you just changed native iOS code. 
Try adding `expo` manually to the `package.json` of your app, see example below (`"expo": "*",`). Usually `nx` updates this itself if it detects a new dependency.
Mine looks like this. Keep `expo` still installed in your workspace level though.

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "*",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "*",
    "react": "*",
    "react-native": "*",
    "react-native-config": "*",
    "react-native-svg": "*"
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the case. Honestly I expected nx had some command to install dependencies top-down. Thanks.

Comment: Actually now it gives another problem...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75057148/metro-unable-to-resolve-module-src-main-when-building-a-react-native-app-fro