# "Unable to resolve module ./src/main" when building a react-native app from an NX monorepo after installing Expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, monorepo

**What I'have done**

- Created a NX monorepo with the react-native preset
- yarn add expo from workspace directory
- added metro dependency manually to package.json in the react native app directory
- pod install in the ios directory of the react native app
- edit of some files manually accordingly to the Expo manual setup guide (https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/)

The only thing that I did different from the original Expo guide is that I edited this line

```
   UIView *rootView = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];
```

in

```
UIView *rootView = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"myappname" initialProperties:nil];
```

Now, the app build fine but metro gives me this error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./src/main from /Users/myusername/Documents/GitHub/folder/monorepo/
```

And that's correct because this is the path to the nx workspace not the react native app directory! Before setting up expo it worked well so I guess expo here is the problem. Do you have any idea of how correct this? It looks that nx and expo are not working very well together.

Comment: can you add example reproducible repo here so we can test and check where is the actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can amend the path in AppDelegate.mm (or AppDelegate.m file. as i know the extension name dependes on react-native version).

[image]

jsBundleURLForBundleRoot point out the wrong path @"src/main" as you see in the image

after i edit the path from src/main to apps/rn-pjt-name/src/main.ts, error disappear

reference: https://github.com/nrwl/nx-react-native/issues/40#issuecomment-979193844

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content](/help/referencing).